# $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2xy - 2xz - 2yz$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x, y, z]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

I am trying to prove that $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2xy - 2xz - 2yz$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x, y, z]$ (I am sure it is) and maybe over $\mathbb{R}[x, y, z]$ (almost sure).

I checked that it is not divisible by $x+y+z$ so factors are not symmetric. And that's where I get confused. Suppose $f = g \cdot h$, then some permutations must  swap $g$ and $h$ and maybe there are some that preserve them. How do I make sure I checked all the possibilities? Is it sufficient to check what happens if $x,y \mapsto y,x$ swaps them and $(123) \in S_3$ swaps them?

Comment: *Hint*: If in a linear factor $(\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z)$ say $\alpha\neq\beta$ then the orbit under $S_3$ will have size at least 3.

Comment: a ternary quadratic form reduces over the complex numbers if and only if the determinant of its Hessian matrix  is zero.  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brookfield_Factoring_Forms_2016.pdf

Comment: One can use Gauss Lemma for $f$ considered as a polynomial in $x$ over $\mathbb Z [y,z]$, and it's easily seen that $f$ has no root in $\mathbb Q(y,z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form factors:  let it be
$$  (ax+by+cz) \cdot (dx+ey+fz)  $$
in which $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are permitted to be real or complex.

Multiply it out, take its second partial derivatives and arrange in the Hessian matrix,

$$
 H= \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
2ad & ae+bd & af+cd \\ 
ae+bd & 2be & bf+ce \\ 
af+cd & bf+ce & 2cf \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Finally, calculate the determinant, which is
$$  \det H = 0 $$

So, if the form factors, the determinant of the Hessian is zero. Contrapositive, if that determinant is nonzero, the form does not factor.

Your Hessian matrix, rather **half** of it, is
$$  \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & -1 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 1 & -1 \\ 
-1 & -1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
and its determinant is nonzero

Comment: It’s a nice solution but a little bit overkill considering that it’s a problem from 9th grade problemsheet :)

Comment: @Vladislav well, if you wish to give detail to your ninth grader, you could say that, for $Px^2 + Q y^2 + R z^2  + Syz + Tzx + Uxy $  this quantity must vanish: $4PQR +STU - PS^2 - QT^2 - R U^2 $ or factoring is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

We observe that, if

$$A(x,y,z):=x^2+y^2+z^2-2xy-2xz-2yz$$

is factorable over $\mathbb R$, then :

$$B(a,b):=1+a^2+b^2-2a-2b-2ab$$

is also factorable over $\mathbb R$ , where $a=\dfrac yx$ and $b=\dfrac zx$ .

Define the variables $(a,b)$ as $a=m+n,\thinspace b=m-n$ . Thus, we can deduce that, if $B(a,b)$ is factorable over $\mathbb R$ then

$$C(m,n):=4n^2-4m+1$$

is factorable too .

But, $C(m,n)=0$ yields $m=n^2+\frac 14$, which makes $a$ and $b$ *quadratic* factors . A contradiction .